# JSF/Primefaces selectonemenu with a mix of select item types

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm refactoring some old stuff over to JSF.  I have a select menu which is used for a filter. The menu is dynamically built for the user and would display their department number and then all supervisors in that department.  The idea is to redisplay the page and filter the content to either all department data or just that supervisors data.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="badge" value="#{bean.badge}" onchange="formHandler()">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{auth.employee.lname}, #{auth.employee.fname}" itemValue="&amp;filter=byBadge&amp;badge=#{auth.employee.badge}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dept #{auth.employee.home_dept_number}" itemValue="&amp;filter=byDept&amp;dept=#{auth.employee.home_dept_number}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.supervisorList}" var="supervisor" itemValue="&amp;filter=byBadge&amp;badge=#{supervisor.badge}"  itemLabel="#{supervisor.lname}, #{supervisor.fname} (D#{supervisor.home_dept_number})"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This would produce HTML as:

```
<option value="&filter=byDept&dept=abc"  >&nbsp;&nbsp;Dept ABC</option>
<option value="&filter=byBadge&badge=12345" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Smith, Mary</option>
<option value="&filter=byBadge&badge=45454" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Jones, John</option>
```

my JavaScript formHandler() builds a new URL with arguments just fine 
`file.xhtml?year=2016&method=pie&method2=week&filter=byBadge&badge=12345`

and the backing bean uses these URL arguments just fine, but the Primefaces selectOneMenu doesn't maintain the properly selected item.

The old way (jsp) I would put do this on the items
`<c:if test="${param.filter == 'byBadge' && auth.employee.badge == param.badge }" >selected</c:if>`

I'm open to other ways to achieve this but don't want to necessarily break out each parameter (filter and badge) into separate widgets.